# "Permission denied" for almost everything after a successful ssh into gcloud instance that was created using bdutil

Tags: hadoop, permission-denied, hortonworks-data-platform, gcloud

Just created instance and deployed a cluster using bdutil. SSH works fine as I can ssh into instance using `./bdutil shell`.

When I try to access directories such as Hadoop, hdfs etc., it throws an error:

> Permission Denied

The terminal appears like this `username@hadoop-m $` I know `hadoop-m` is the name of the instance. What is the username? It says my name but I don't know where it got this from or what the password is.

I am using Ubuntu to ssh into the instance.

Answer (score 1):

Not a hadoop expert, I can answer a bit generally.  On GCE when you ssh in gcloud creates a username from you google account name.  Hadoop directories such as `hadoop` or `hdfs` are probably owned by a different user.  Please try using `sudo chmod` to make give your username permissions to read/write the directories you need.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on Jeff's answer, bdutil-deployed clusters set up the user `hadoop` as the Hadoop admin (this 'admin' user may differ on different Hadoop systems, where Hadoop admin accounts may be split into separate users `hdfs`, `yarn`, `mapred`, etc). Note that bdutil clusters should work without needing deal with Hadoop admin stuff for normal jobs, but if you need to access those Hadoop directories, you can either do:

```
sudo su hadoop
```

or

```
sudo su
```

to open a shell as `hadoop` or `root`, respectively. Or as Jeff mentions, you can `sudo chmod` to grant broader access to your own username.